# Electron-packager is generating correct .app file Electron-Builder is showing blank screen

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, notarize

I was using [electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager) to generate .app file from my Angular-Electron app and then [electron-installer-dmg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-installer-dmg) to generate installable .dmg file from .app. But I have to add Notarizing to my app which I [could not figure out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321290/notarizing-electron-app-with-electron-installer-dmg-without-electron-builder) how to do with electron-installer-dmg, so I am switching to [Electron-Builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder). My app is showing blank screen when build with Electron-Builder while working correctly when I generate .app file using electron-packager which shows there is no path issue. My Electron-Builder configurations look like that:

```
"build": {
    "mac": {
      "icon": "build/icon2.ico",
      "target": [
        "dmg"
      ]
    },
    "files": [
      "**/*"
      "*.js",
      "build",
      "node_modules",
      "package.json"
    ],
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  }
```

Resulting file (both .app and .dmg) is showing blank screen. Devtools are also not showing any erros:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I would look for additional things to debug next: do you get any output from the main process by starting the app in a terminal - the devtools show you the errors from the renderer process. You shouldn't need to include the node_modules or the package.json into the files array, if build contains only resources you need for building this may conflict if included. If you have files that can't be run from an ASAR archive (like java executables for example) you may want to put them in extraResources instead.